# sails.js how to pass to view variables from multiple models

Tags: javascript, callback, sails.js, waterline

everyone, I am learning sails.js, and have a question (here's my code in the controller):

```
var test;
User.find().exec(function callBack(err,results){
                    //console.log(results);
                      test = results; //not working;
                    });

Reminder.find().exec(function callBack(err,reminders){
                    });
```

I want to pass the results from the two queries to my view:

```
return res.view('reminder/bla', 
    {
        users: users,
        reminders: reminders
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty ugly but it will work. Yes, you would be better off doing this in parallel (concurrently) & NPM modules such as async, or a promises library using (eg. Q.All) could help here. But if you are just stuck and wish to get this out the door just nest them inside each other.

Warning - this will execute one after the other.

```
// entry inside Controller method here..

var test;
User.find().exec(function callBack(err, users){

  Reminder.find().exec(function callBack(err, reminders){

    return res.view('reminder/bla',
      {
        users: users,
        reminders: reminders
      });

  });

});
```

One approach to do the above concurrently would be to use [async.parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async) - of the form of:

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

Another approach is to use a Promises library. SailsJS uses [BlueBird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) (since version 0.11.0), and earlier versions used [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).

Q.All is of the form of:

```
    return Q.all([
        promise1,
        promise2
    ]).spread(function (resultFromPromise1, resultFromPromise2) {
      // do something with the results...
});
```

You could easy use one of the above approaches to parallelise the **`User.find()`** and **`Reminder.find()`** function calls such that they execute concurrently.

I don't have your code sample / Sails instance open so won't hazard trying to write the specific syntax in this answer. However, if you try to use one of the approaches above and get stuck, then please update your question and will be happy to take a look.

Simple illustration of each approach as follows (using simple logic for demo only)

Using **Async.js**

```
var async = require('async');

var task = function (cb, count) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    cb(null, "complete: " + count);
  }, 1000);
};

async.parallel([
  function (cb) {
    task(cb, 'one');
  },
  function (cb) {
    task(cb, 'two');
  }
], function (err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  //[ 'complete: one', 'complete: two' ]
});
```

Using **Q**:

```
var Q = require('q');

function task1(cb, count) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  setTimeout(function () {
    return deferred.resolve(cb(null, count));
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}

var myCb = function (err, count) {
  return "complete: " + count;
};

Q.all([task1(myCb, 'one'), task1(myCb, 'two')])
  .then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
    //[ 'complete: one', 'complete: two' ]
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, man, it worked! Please write the async/promise solution :)

Comment: Ok, will update answer, pleased to have helped. ps. I do hope you are making some kind of effort to check whether "err" is populated :D

Comment: Thanks for everyting, I tried all methods. The most I like is with Q. And yes, I will try not to forgot checking for errors :)

Comment: @ZaharyShinikchiev - no probs, JS is a really fun language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use promise methods or tools like [async](http://ss.com), [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or nodejs native Promise.